# Source on Wordpress contains mangled Twitter data (hurting SEO?)

Tags: seo, wordpress

I have a Twitter account linked to my WordPress site so that each tweet becomes a new post.

I was wondering why my SEO was hurting and when I looked at the source I saw stuff like this at the top of the page:

Los Conchita & # 8 2 1 7 ; s on Prince has V & # 8 2 3 0 ;

Has anyone else had this problem and know why it is occurring? Thanks!

The site is reviewathens.com

Comment: Seems to be fixed now?

Also using the multiple dates as H1 tags is very bad SEO practice I recommend you do some reading on the basics of SEO on the web

Comment: What Blowsie said. There's a lot more wrong with your SEO than just your automated posts.

Comment: I was getting similar behavior with the four digit string of numbers, usually starting with an 8. This would happen even if I weren't posting a URL from my WordPress blog! It stopped in early March, I never found out what was going on. But you weren't the only one @Davey !

Answer (score 1):

Search engines penalize for duplicate content that they think by default to be redundant or spam. Some sites attempt to spam by copying text off of other sites ranked highly in search engines, but this will get you flagged. So if you just have an rss reader or something similar that copies every post over that could have a bad impact. Maybe search engines associate the keywords in your recent posts with undesirable content. It wouldn't hurt to run your page through the w3 validator to tidy up the code, if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a plug-in on WordPress to retrieve the tweets, it could be the plug-in or its settings. It could also be the alpha-numerics that you're using. Sometimes the "&" sign does not get carried over well. Instead of using "&" use "and" Try using more letters than symbols and numbers.